# php arrays: how to put given integers as key

Tags: php, arrays

I need to give pre-defined integers as key for an array (I need the integer key, as this will be stored in an integer field in a database). I can specify strings as a key, but if I try to submit in integer, the array ignores my key specification and assigns outomaticalls 0,1,2, .. as key.

Here my sample code

```
   public function TestArray ()
     { 
        $valuesForIndexOfArray = array(100,101,102);
        //$valuesForIndexOfArray = array('l','m','n','o','p');   // in this case the string values are used in the index
        $resultArray = array();
        foreach ($valuesForIndexOfArray as $singleIndexValue ){
            $dummyValue = "dummytext-".$singleIndexValue;      
            $indexOfResultArray = $singleIndexValue;
            //$indexOfResultArray = $indexOfResultArray." ";  // !!! only if made to string, singleAnswerId appears in index, otherwise autoindex 0,1,2,          
            $newElementForResultArray = array($indexOfResultArray => $dummyValue);  
            $resultArray = array_merge($resultArray, $newElementForResultArray);
        }
        return ($resultArray);
     }
```

If I run the code as above, i get ( with dump in symfony, twig)

[image]

If I use //$indexOfResultArray = $indexOfResultArray." "; and make it a string I the index looks almost as it should - but as string, which does not help me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am having problems understanding what you are really asking about. Integer index is perfectly fine thing and you can set it up to whatever you want:

```
<?php
$a = array(
        1 => 'foo',
        100 => 'bar',
);

var_dump($a);

$a = array();
$a[1] = 'foo';
$a[100] = 'bar';

var_dump($a);
```

which would produce

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  string(3) "foo"
  [100]=>
  string(3) "bar"
}
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  string(3) "foo"
  [100]=>
  string(3) "bar"
}
```

as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating a new array and then merging each time? Try just appending values:

```
 public function TestArray ()
         { 
            $valuesForIndexOfArray = array(100,101,102);
            $resultArray = array();
            foreach ($valuesForIndexOfArray as $singleIndexValue ){
                $dummyValue = "dummytext-".$singleIndexValue;      
                $resultArray[$singleIndexValue] = $dummyValue
            }
            return $resultArray;
         }
```

Comment: you do not need brackets for `return` - it's not a function.

Comment: I copied already existing code that was provided. But you are right, will update it.